# ¿Cómo puedo escribir esta promesa con await y async?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Me sucede que la página **crashea** porque no le da tiempo de recibir la promesa, es decir cuando la vuelvo a cargar el error desaparece pero quiero evitar que aparezca  en la primera vez que cargo la página para lograr esto quiero usar **asyn** y **await**.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getProducts } from './apiCore';

const Home = () => {
  const [productsByArrival, setProductsByArrival] = useState([]);
  
  const loadProductByArrival = () => {
        getProducts("createdAt").then(data => {
            if(data.error) {
                setError(data.error);
            } else {
                setProductsByArrival(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Aquí muestro el método **getProducts method** y quisiera saber como convertirlo en una promesa con **await** y **async**.

```js
export const getProducts = (sortBy) => {
    return fetch(`${API}/products?sortBy=${sortBy}&order=desc&limit=6`, {
        method: "GET"
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: que tal si imprimes data, te esta dando error intentando acceder a un elemento, probablemente data es null o undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu patrón para convertir en async-await sería como:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getProducts } from './apiCore';

const Home = async () => {
  const [productsByArrival, setProductsByArrival] = useState([]);

  const loadProductByArrival = async () => {
  try {
    data = await getProducts("createdAt");
    setProductsByArrival(data);
  }
  catch(ex) {
    setError(ex)
  }
};    
}
```

y

```
export const getProducts = async (sortBy) => {
  await fetch(`${API}/products?sortBy=${sortBy}&order=desc&limit=6`, {
  method: "GET"  });
}
```

tu llamada a Home no se altera.
Por otro lado, para que tu resultado no haga crash, lo que hay que hacer es inicializar tu componente con un mensaje ad hoc (a propósito), para que no presente nada mientras carga. y en cuanto recibas los datos, actualizar el state.

Comment: que es ad hoc? como seria esta inicializacion?

Comment: ah ya lo arregle borre node-modules y package.lock-json y corri npm install y problema resuelto, no se que habra pasado.

Comment: ad hoc significa a propósito, o sea que pongas un mensaje en tu pantalla como "Cargando....". La idea es poner uin condicional (if) en tu render para que cuando sea indefinida tu lista de datos ponga un letrero solamente. y cuando se actualize el estado con los datos de la carga de datos y se actualize te ponga el render con datos:

Answer (score 2):

Usar `catch` en los servicios puede llegar a ser una mala idea si no relanzas o transformas la excepción porque el consumidor del servicio no puede saber si ocurrió un error o no.

Cambia tu servicio a esto:

```
export const getProducts = (sortBy) => {
    return fetch(`${API}/products?sortBy=${sortBy}&order=desc&limit=6`, {
        method: "GET"
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);

        // Relanza el error para notificar al consumidor
        return Promise.reject(err);
    })
}
```

También podrías eliminar completamente el `catch` del servicio. Yo personalmente lo prefiero así porque casi siempre los errores requieren un feedback visual al usuario.

Como última alternativa puedes retornar un objeto con un par de propiedades como `error` o `data` pero esto complicaría un poco tu capacidad de controlar el flujo de los errores al eliminar el canal del error de la cadena de promesas.

Luego en tu componente:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getProducts } from './apiCore';

const Home = () => {
    const [productsByArrival, setProductsByArrival] = useState([]);

    const loadProductByArrival = () => {
        getProducts("createdAt").then(data => {
            setProductsByArrival(data);
        }).catch(err => {
            setError(err);
        });
    }
}
```

Traducido a `async` y `await`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getProducts } from './apiCore';

const Home = () => {
    const [productsByArrival, setProductsByArrival] = useState([]);

    const loadProductByArrival = async () => {
        try {
            setProductsByArrival(await getProducts("createdAt"));
        } catch (err) {
            setError(err);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: en return Promise.reject(err); me dice que err no esta definido

Comment: agregue una foto del error.

Comment: @CeciResponde `err` si esta definido. La foto que pones dice *Cannot read property `error`*. No has modificado el código del componente si te está dando ese error. `if (data.error)` no está en ningín lugar de mi respuesta. Lee nuevamente la respuesta completa.

Comment: el error de la foto es el error de mi código, no del tuyo, con tu código me dice err undifined en Promise.reject(err);

Comment: @CeciResponde Ya actualicé, perdona tenia un parentesis de más y me faltaba cerrar el bloque de código. La sintaxis era inválida. Vuelve a probar que ahora no te debe dar error